# attribution issues involving for loops

Tags: javascript

I am trying to remove items from an array. But i have to do it from each item from it. For that, I used a for loop, and ,in the begging of the loop, I try to renovate the array values by using the const `seq`.

But the sequence array keeps decreasing it's length as the for loop runs.
I am trying to remove one item, do some stuff and put it back to the array so I can do the same thing with the next item.

```
const q = sequence;
for(let i= sequence.length-1; i>=0 ; i--){
        sequence = q;
        sequence.splice(i,1,);
        console.log(sequence);   
           //do some other stuff here

}
```

output ex:

```
Input:sequence: [1, 3, 2]

Console Output:[ 1, 3 ]
               [ 1 ]
               []

what i expected: [1, 3]
                 [1, 2]
                 [3,2]
```

Comment: `sequence = q;` does not copy the array, it just stores the reference to the array in a second variable

Comment: as i know you want all possible subarray  having length one lesser than existing array?

Comment: ```var subsetArray = (function() {
  return {
    getResult: getResult
  }

  function getResult(array, n) {

    function isBigEnough(value) {
      return value.length === n;
    }

    var ps = [
      []
    ];
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0, len = ps.length; j < len; j++) {
        ps.push(ps[j].concat(array[i]));
      }
    }
    return ps.filter(isBigEnough);
  }
})();



 var arr = [1, 2, 3];
 console.log(subsetArray.getResult(arr,2));```